# Stationary points of piecewise function

Tags: derivatives

I'm studying a piecewise function:

$$ y = f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \quad x \geq 0 \\ 1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2} &  \text{otherwise}  \end{cases} $$

The first derivative is:

$$ f'(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \quad x > 0 \\ \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &  \text{if } -1 < x < 0  \end{cases} $$

The proposed solution I'm checking states (I'm translating from Italian): "There are infinite stationary points, those of the half-line $y > 0$, which are weak minima"

My question is: Why $y > 0$? Shouldn't it be $x > 0$, if the stationary (critical) points are those where the first derivative is zero?

I also don't understand why the first interval should change (always according to my text) from $x \geq 0$ to $x > 0$. Are the things linked somehow?

Comment: I don't know what interval you are talking about. You need to learn to describe what you are asking about and not assume that we know what you are referring to.

Comment: f(x) = 0 if x >=0, and later f'(x) = 0 if x > 0.

Comment: Yes I guessed after I commented. Indeed as I said in my answer there is no reason to exclude $f'(0)$, but one needs to give **justification** as it is clearly not guaranteed to be differentiable in-between pieces!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. It must be a typo since there is no $y$ anywhere to be seen...

About your new question, I guess you are asking why $f'(0)$ is not defined? In fact it is $0$, so I also don't know why your book excludes it. You can check that $f(t) = f(0) + 0 t + o(t)$ as $t \to 0$, or equivalently $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t)}{t} = 0$, and hence $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, in this case I'll write directly to the author of the text.

Comment: @user21820 Ok, I deleted my first comment (+1)